# "Next" button page in a R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I want to asking. How to make button next page in shiny R with this code?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyalert)
library(rvest)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
    
    # H E A D E R
    
    dashboardHeaderPlus(title = tagList(
        span(class = "logo-lg", "NAMA APP"), 
        img(src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/204/204074.svg"))),
    
    # S I D E B A R
    
    dashboardSidebar(
        
        sidebarMenu(id = "menu",
                    menuItem(tabName = "korelasi", "Dashboard", icon = icon("project-diagram", lib = "font-awesome")),
                    menuItem(tabName = "tingkat", "Check",icon = icon("user-check", lib = "font-awesome")),
                    menuItem(tabName = "tentang", "Tentang", icon = icon("address-card", lib = "font-awesome"))
                    # Add buttons to choose the way you want to select your data
        )),
    
    # B O D Y
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(tabName = "korelasi",
                    h2("Korelasi")
            ),
            tabItem(tabName = "tentang",
                    h2("about")
            ),
            tabItem(tabName = "tingkat",
                    fluidRow(
                        column(
                            #IDENTITAS
                            box(width = 12,
                                height = "100%",
                                textInput("projnama", "Nama"),
                                selectInput("projumur", "Umur", c("Pilih Jawaban"='', "60":"100")),
                                selectInput("projgender", "Jenis Kelamin", c("Pilih Jawaban"='', "Laki-Laki","Perempuan"))
                            ),

#I WANT BUTTON NEXT PAGE HERE, SO THE NEXT PAGE IS "ADLS"

                            #ADLS
                            box(title="Dalam 30 hari terakhir, seberapa sulit Anda melakukan aktivitas berikut ini:", width = 12, collapsible = FALSE, 
                                #SOAL 1
                                box(status = "warning",
                                    title = "Mandi",
                                    solidHeader = TRUE,
                                    width = 12,
                                    height = "100%",
                                    bsButton("s1p1", "Tidak ada masalah",width ="100%"),
                                    br(), br(),
                                    actionButton("s1p2", "Ringan",width ="100%"),
                                    br(), br(),
                                    actionButton("s1p3", "Sedang",width ="100%"),
                                    br(), br(),
                                    actionButton("s1p4", "Sangat berat/tidak bisa",width ="100%"),
                                    br(), br(),
                                    textOutput("count1")
                                ),
                                #SOAL 2
                                box(status = "warning",
                                    title="Berpakaian",
                                    solidHeader = T,
                                    width = 12,
                                    height = "100%",
                                    actionButton("s2p1", "Tidak ada masalah",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    actionButton("s2p2", "Ringan",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    actionButton("s2p3", "Sedang",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    actionButton("s2p4", "Sangat berat/tidak bisa",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    textOutput("count2")
                                ),
                                #SOAL 3
                                box(status = "warning",
                                    title="Makan",
                                    solidHeader = T,
                                    width = 12,
                                    height = "100%",
                                    actionButton("s3p1", "Tidak ada masalah",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    actionButton("s3p2", "Ringan",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    actionButton("s3p3", "Sedang",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    actionButton("s3p4", "Sangat berat/tidak bisa",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    textOutput("count3")
                                ),
                                #SOAL 4
                                box(status = "warning",
                                    title="Bangun dari kondisi berbaring (transfer)",
                                    solidHeader = T,
                                    width = 12,
                                    height = "100%",
                                    actionButton("s4p1", "Tidak ada masalah",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    actionButton("s4p2", "Ringan",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    actionButton("s4p3", "Sedang",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    actionButton("s4p4", "Sangat berat/tidak bisa",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    textOutput("count4")
                                ),
                                #SOAL 5
                                box(status = "warning",
                                    title="Pergi ke toilet dan menggunakan toilet",
                                    solidHeader = T,
                                    width = 12,
                                    height = "100%",
                                    actionButton("s5p1", "Tidak ada masalah",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    actionButton("s5p2", "Ringan",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    actionButton("s5p3", "Sedang",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    actionButton("s5p4", "Sangat berat/tidak bisa",width ="100%"),
                                    br(),br(),
                                    textOutput("count5")
                                )),
                            
                            width = 12)),
            ))
        
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    
}

# Return a Shiny app objectshinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
ui <- dashboardPage(

  # H E A D E R

  dashboardHeader(title = "Social Media Metrics", titleWidth = 320),
  # dashboardHeaderPlus(title = tagList(
  #   #span(class = "logo-lg", "NAMA APP"),
  #   #img(src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/204/204074.svg")
  #   )),

  # S I D E B A R

  dashboardSidebar(

    sidebarMenu(id = "menu",
                menuItem(tabName = "korelasi", "Dashboard", icon = icon("project-diagram", lib = "font-awesome")),
                menuItem(tabName = "tingkat", "Check",icon = icon("user-check", lib = "font-awesome")),
                menuItem("Tentang", tabName = "tentang",  icon = icon("address-card", lib = "font-awesome")),
                # Add buttons to choose the way you want to select your data
                menuItem("Tentang1", tabName = "tentang1",  icon = icon("address-card", lib = "font-awesome")),
                menuItem("Tentang2", tabName = "tentang2",  icon = icon("address-card", lib = "font-awesome"))

    )),

  # B O D Y
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "korelasi",
              h2("Korelasi")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "tingkat",
              h2("about")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "tentang",
              fluidRow(
                column(width=12,
                  #IDENTITAS
                  box(width = 12,
                      height = "100%",
                      textInput("projnama", "Nama"),
                      selectInput("projumur", "Umur", c("Pilih Jawaban"='', "60":"100")),
                      selectInput("projgender", "Jenis Kelamin", c("Pilih Jawaban"='', "Laki-Laki","Perempuan"))
                  )
                )), actionButton(inputId="ok1", label="NEXT")
      ),
                  #I WANT BUTTON NEXT PAGE HERE, SO THE NEXT PAGE IS "ADLS"
      tabItem(tabName = "tentang1",
              fluidRow(
                column(width=12,
                  #ADLS
                  box(title="Dalam 30 hari terakhir, seberapa sulit Anda melakukan aktivitas berikut ini:", width = 12, collapsible = FALSE,
                      #SOAL 1
                      box(status = "warning",
                          title = "Mandi",
                          solidHeader = TRUE,
                          width = 12,
                          height = "100%",
                          bsButton("s1p1", "Tidak ada masalah",width ="100%"),
                          br(), br(),
                          actionButton("s1p2", "Ringan",width ="100%"),
                          br(), br(),
                          actionButton("s1p3", "Sedang",width ="100%"),
                          br(), br(),
                          actionButton("s1p4", "Sangat berat/tidak bisa",width ="100%"),
                          br(), br(),
                          textOutput("count1")
                      ),
                      #SOAL 2
                      box(status = "warning",
                          title="Berpakaian",
                          solidHeader = T,
                          width = 12,
                          height = "100%",
                          actionButton("s2p1", "Tidak ada masalah",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          actionButton("s2p2", "Ringan",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          actionButton("s2p3", "Sedang",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          actionButton("s2p4", "Sangat berat/tidak bisa",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          textOutput("count2")
                      )
                  ))
              ), 
              fluidRow(column(12, div(actionButton(inputId="ok2", label="NEXT"), style="float:right")))
      ),
      #I WANT BUTTON NEXT PAGE HERE, SO THE NEXT PAGE IS "ADLS"
      tabItem(tabName = "tentang2",
              fluidRow(
                column(width=12,
                  box(title="Dalam 30 hari terakhir, seberapa sulit Anda melakukan aktivitas berikut ini:", width = 12, collapsible = FALSE,
                      #SOAL 3
                      box(status = "warning",
                          title="Makan",
                          solidHeader = T,
                          width = 12,
                          height = "100%",
                          actionButton("s3p1", "Tidak ada masalah",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          actionButton("s3p2", "Ringan",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          actionButton("s3p3", "Sedang",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          actionButton("s3p4", "Sangat berat/tidak bisa",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          textOutput("count3")
                      ),
                      #SOAL 4
                      box(status = "warning",
                          title="Bangun dari kondisi berbaring (transfer)",
                          solidHeader = T,
                          width = 12,
                          height = "100%",
                          actionButton("s4p1", "Tidak ada masalah",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          actionButton("s4p2", "Ringan",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          actionButton("s4p3", "Sedang",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          actionButton("s4p4", "Sangat berat/tidak bisa",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          textOutput("count4")
                      ),
                      #SOAL 5
                      box(status = "warning",
                          title="Pergi ke toilet dan menggunakan toilet",
                          solidHeader = T,
                          width = 12,
                          height = "100%",
                          actionButton("s5p1", "Tidak ada masalah",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          actionButton("s5p2", "Ringan",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          actionButton("s5p3", "Sedang",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          actionButton("s5p4", "Sangat berat/tidak bisa",width ="100%"),
                          br(),br(),
                          textOutput("count5")
                      ))
                )
      ))

  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$ok1, {
    updateTabItems(session, "menu", "tentang1") 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$ok2, {
    updateTabItems(session, "menu", "tentang2") 
  })
  
}

# Return a Shiny app objectshinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: sorry, I mean the next button in under form "identitas", in the same menu item

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  Perhaps you can clarify a bit more in your question.

Comment: you put the next button in the "menu sub item", I hope it is under the box (nama, umur, jenis kelamin). Sorry I can't upload image :(